# Gridview WebUserControl access selected row

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a grid view in the web custom control and want to select any row and so that i can edit that row. the edit button is on the master page and default.aspx is inherited from that master and know i want the row id on my defult page so that i can edit that row easily.

my web user control is

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grvBranches" GridLines="None" 
  AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="5" 
  OnRowDataBound="grvBranches_RowDataBound" 
  OnRowCancelingEdit="grvBranches_RowCancelingEdit" 
  OnRowEditing="grvBranches_RowEditing" 
  OnRowUpdating="grvBranches_RowUpdating">
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#d8d8d8" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#d8d8d8" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:Label Text="BranchName" ID="lblHeaderBranchName" runat="server" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' ID="lblID" Visible="false" runat="server" />
                <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Branch_Name") %>' ID="lblBranchName" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:Label Text="OrganizationName" ID="lblHeaderOrganizationName" runat="server" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Organization_Name") %>' ID="lblOrganizationName" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:Label Text="Address" ID="lblHeaderAddress" runat="server" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Address_1") %>' ID="lblAddress" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:Label Text="City" ID="lblHeaderCityName" runat="server" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("City_Name") %>' ID="lblCityName" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField />
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and i want this rowid in on my Default page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your master page .cs, on the EditButton click event

```
GridView gView = ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("GridView1") as GridView;
// use gView.SelectedIndex to manipulate the row, edit it, etc
```

Assuming your main ContentPlaceHolder's ID is 'ContentPlaceHolder1'